# How to reference the data of an existing GeoJSON leaflet object?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

We have a Leaflet Map which we are trying to build using GeoJSON.  Our data comes in from a live stream, so we start out by initializing the GeoJSON with empty data:

```
var myLayer = L.geoJson([], {
  style: function(feature) {
    var color = getDataband(LATENCY_BANDS, feature.properties.latency).color;

    return { 
      fillColor: color
    };
  },

  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  },

  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    var latency = feature.properties.latency;

    for (var i = 0; i < ENABLED_LATENCY_BANDS.length; i++) {
      if (ENABLED_LATENCY_BANDS[i].contains(latency)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
});
```

Then we add the data points one by one as messages come in from the live stream by calling:

```
var geojsonFeature = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "latency": sample.latency
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [location.longitude, location.latitude]
  }
};

myLayer.addData(geojsonFeature);
```

However, our filter dynamically changes based on user input.  Therefore, we need to remove all existing data and re-add all data to the map whenever the user input changes in order for the new filter to apply to all existing and new data.  We tried calling the following whenever the user input changes:

```
    map.removeLayer(myLayer);
    myLayer.addTo(map);
```

However, when `myLayer` is re-added to the map, the old data are wiped out and only new data appear.

It seems like we should be re-initializing the `myLayer` object before we call `myLayer.addTo(map)`, but we don't know how to re-initialize `myLayer` with the existing feature data.  Documentation does not explain how to reference the data of the GeoJSON leaflet object.

How do we reference the data of a GeoJSON leaflet object?

Thanks.

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`filter`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson-filter) option has effect only at instantiation and when using `.addData()` method. Furthermore, when a feature is filtered out, it is not just "hidden", it is *not recorded* in memory (i.e. not within that group).

It is strange that your old data is wiped out by removing the group and adding it back to the map, should you have changed the filter conditions or not.

Anyway, there is probably no documentation about how to "reference the data of the GeoJSON Leaflet object" in the sense that you are trying to achieve, because it is implementation dependent.

In your case, you would need to *accumulate* your features in a hidden group / array, so that whenever your filter conditions change, you can re-evaluate these features through the new filter.

For example, you could do something like:

```js
var accumulatedFeatures = [];

// When data arrives
accumulatedFeatures.push(geojsonFeature);
myLayer.addData(geojsonFeature);

// When filter conditions change
myLayer.clearLayers(); // http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers
myLayer.addData(accumulatedFeatures); // Re-evaluate all data through new filter
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have to store a separate list outside of GeoJSON, but this works.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi again.  This is basically working but it has an unintended consequence.  I am not really able to view popups for features anymore.  If I click a popup, it will display briefly and dismiss itself.  It's not too surprising because at any given moment any feature could update or be removed, which causes  `clearLayers` and `addData` to be called.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, without seeing your code, it is hard to tell. Why do you call clear layers when data arrives, instead of only when filter changes? Would probably fit better in a new question.

Comment: My code is pretty big at this point and it might be hard to simplify it to show in a comment, but basically my features are coming in one at a time in a stream.  I don't have all my features at once.  So I add each feature to `accumulatedFeatures` and call addData, but the features have 1-minute timers on them.  So the features start getting removed one by one.  To remove them, I get rid of them individually in `accumulatedFeatures`, call `clearLayers`, and call `addData`.  So I am clearing more frequently than when the filter is changed.

Comment: You should really make a new question and show the minimum code that reproduces your issue.