# How to modify or remove some existing data in GeoJSON Leaflet object?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, geojson

Recently I asked about [referencing the data of an existing GeoJSON Leaflet object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776919/how-to-reference-the-data-of-an-existing-geojson-leaflet-object).  My Leaflet map consists of data coming in a stream to my GeoJSON Leaflet object.  User inputs can change a filter for the GeoJSON data, so to make the filter apply to both the existing and new data I am keeping track of my data in an array called `myFeatures`.  Whenever the filters change or an item in `myFeatures` changes, I do the following:

```
myGeoJson.clearLayers();
myGeoJson.addData(myFeatures);
```

This is working to make my map update according to the newly updated feature data or the changes in the filter.

I am applying pop-ups to the GeoJSON object when I initialize my GeoJSON object:

```
var myGeoJson = L.geoJson(myFeatures, {
  style: function(feature) {
    ...
  },

  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  },

  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    ...
  },

  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
    }
  }
});
```

When I click on an individual feature, the pop-up appears.  However, the pop-up dismisses pretty quickly, thanks to `clearLayers` and `addData` being called.  :(

Is there some kind of way to stop the pop-up dismissing in this situation?

Or - better question - is there a way to modifying existing data in a GeoJSON object or remove some (not all) data from a GeoJSON object?

To provide some context, my GeoJSON shows circle markers for each feature.  The circle markers are colored based on a property of the feature.  The property can actually change over time, so the marker's styling needs to be updated.  A marker also times out after a while and needs to be removed from the map, but the other markers need to stay on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are for sure better ways to do that, but if you don't want to modify your code architecture too much, you could just create your popups in a specific layer, which you won't clear when you add your new data.

To give you an idea (markers play below the role of myGeoJson in your example):

```
var popup_id = {};
var popup_layer = new L.layerGroup();
var markers = new L.layerGroup();

$.each(testData, function(index, p) {
   var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(p.lat, p.lon));
   markers.addLayer(marker);
   popup = new L.popup({offset:  new L.Point(0, -30)});
   popup.setLatLng(L.latLng(p.lat, p.lon));
   popup.setContent(p.text);
   popup_id[p.id] = popup;
   marker.on('click', function() {
      popup_id[p.id].openPopup();
      popup_layer.addLayer(popup_id[p.id]);
      markers.clearLayers();
   })
});

popup_layer.addTo(map);
markers.addTo(map);
```

You also keep track of all your popups in a dictionary popup_id.
Since you haven't provided us with a JSfiddle it is a bit difficult to find the perfect answer for your case, but I hope that the popup layer (also [here in my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaillant/pmfq9d4d/)) gives you a good direction.

Comment: Your separate layer for the popups worked.  Thanks.  But I am curious, what are the "better ways of doing that"?